# excel vba listobject HeaderRowsRange

Tags: excel, vba, range, hidden, listobject

I am working with list objects in excel and there is one thing that puzzles me:
according to [this](http://vba.relief.jp/excel-vba-get-table-header-row-address/) and many other sites I visited the following line of code is a range:

```
mytable.headerRowRange("nameofColumn")
```

mytable being a listobject of a particular sheet.

what I wand to do is hide that column

but this would not work:

```
mytable.headerRowRange("nameofColumn").EntireColumn.Hidden=True
```

Why?

the error is: Invalid procedure call or argument.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mytable.ListColumns("ID").Range.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Comment: ++That's the correct way to do it.  using HeaderRowRange with text value will work and return address  Excel columns and not the ListObject columns.

Comment: @cyboashu which one is the method you mean

Comment: @JoseBerlines use `ListColumns` as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have done

```
mytable.HeaderRowRange.Find("id").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Comment: This uses the fact that HeaderRowRange is a Range object and therefore has a Find method to search for the column of interest.